# Data interpolation using cubic spline in SAS

Tags: sas, interpolation

I need help with interpolating growth data. So my data contains weight information at various time points for each participant, I need to interpolate their weight at the exact 0,12,24,36 months using a cubic spline model. Any ideas on how to do it in SAS? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
DATA Have;
INPUT id age weight;
DATALINES;
1 0 4
1 2.2 6
1 5 8
1 10 20
1 11.3 28
1 28 40
1 40 53
2 0 3
2 1.5 8
2 4.9 15
2 6.4 20
2 14.9 40
2 31 50
2 41 66
3 0 6
3 2.8 11
3 6.1 23
3 9.4 36
3 19.1 40
3 37 51
;
RUN;
```

I tried proc expand, but not sure how it works since i have repeated measures

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions.

- Age is month
- To calculate a 'date' for months that have a decimal
  assume 30.4375 (365.25/12) days as month is not a standard duration
- Assume you're interpolating for beginning of the month (if not change the parameters in the OBSERVED option. (Middle does seem more accurate).

```
*make fake data;
DATA Have;
INPUT id age weight;
*create monthly date based on age;
age_date = intnx('month', '01Jan2000'd, int(age), 's') + (age-int(age))*30.4375;
format age_date date9.;
DATALINES;
1 0 4
1 2.2 6
1 5 8
1 10 20
1 11.3 28
1 28 40
1 40 53
2 0 3
2 1.5 8
2 4.9 15
2 6.4 20
2 14.9 40
2 31 50
2 41 66
3 0 6
3 2.8 11
3 6.1 23
3 9.4 36
3 19.1 40
3 37 51
;
RUN;

*interpolate;
proc expand data=have out=want to=month;
by id;
id age_date;
  convert weight / observed=(beginning, average);
run;

*combine real data and calculated date;
data combined;
set have want indsname=source;
dsn = source;
run;

*sort for graphing;
proc sort data=combined;
by id dsn;
run;

*graphing results;
proc sgplot data=combined;
by id;
series x=age_date y=weight /group = dsn;
run;
```